# define knockout logic for dependant arrays for dropdowns

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am having WebApi that returns Countries with Companies.

The object returned is in the following format:

```
[{"$id":"1", "Name":"Denmark", "Currency":"DKK", "Companies":[],",
{"$id":"2","Name":"Belgium","Currency":"EUR","Companies":[],

{"$id":"3","Name":"Austria","Currency":"EUR","Companies":[{"$id":"4","Name":"Belgium Company 1"},...]
```

So, there is a list of Countries and each Country has a list of companies.

How to map this structure to knockout?

I have knockout model `viewModel` with different properties:

```
 this.objectId = ko.observable();
 this.Country = ko.observable(); // this is selected country for given object
 this.Countries = ko.observableArray();
 this.Company = ko.observable(); //this is selected company for given object
 this.Companies = ko.observableArray();
 this.ContactName = ko.observable();
 ...
```

When page loads I am populating viewModel and binding UI. During this I also call webApi and get countries+companies in the format as described above.

```
    function _getCountries() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/api/portfolio/GetCountries",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET"
    });
}
```

I am calling _getCountries during model initialization that loads model data like objectId, ContactName etc. When this init is done, I am calling _getCountries:

```
 _getCountries().done(function (dataJson) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJson, {}, ParentModel.ChildModelInst.Countries);
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("fail");
    });
```

`this.Countries` and `this.Companies` should be used to populate dropdowns, for example:

```
<select data-bind="options: Countries, value: Country"></select>
```

**The question/problem:**
1) Above doens't work, because Countries consists of objects and it shows me dropdown with "objects"

2) I need somehow define Countries and Companies so that those are related. If I change countries then appropriate companies are loaded into dropdown. (so this.Companies should be loaded accordingly to this.Country that is selected item from this.Countries).

Comment: you have not shown all part of your ajax call. please show all part of your ajax call. I cant see in ajax call how are you assigning result to observable array Countries

Comment: Also you want to show 2 drop downs? one with country and other with companies?

Comment: I have updated text a bit, I am not able to show all code, it is complicated.

Comment: Can you try following <select data-bind="options: Countries, value: id,optionsText: 'Name'"></select>

Comment: Even if this works, it is not related to Companies.

Comment: you have not shown your code for company dropdown

Comment: I do not have company dropdown, I do not know how to map it from countries json.

Comment: you have to do subscribe event on Country dropdown and then fill comapany dropdown from value you select from country dropdown

Comment: can you put up small fiddle for json object stored in observable array and bind to country dropdown? I will then show how to load company dropdown

Comment: Here is fiddle, but it is not working. I am unable to get it work (mapping park gives error). http://jsfiddle.net/qW822/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42102/discussion-between-renathy-and-ashreva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to created computed observable to get company names. So i suggest following.

Html for Country and Company dropdown

```
<select data-bind="options: Countries, value: Country, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>

<select data-bind="options: filteredCompanies, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

On subscribe event of "Country" created computed function to return list of Companies for the selected Countries

```
this.Country.subscribe(function(value) {

      self.filteredCompanies = ko.computed(function() {

          if (value.Companies != undefined){
              return value.Companies;

          }

        });

 });
```

Comment: I have managed to do this using "with" keyword, is it somehow related to what you suggested?

Comment: yes thats ok. is your problem solved now? if yes then can you accept answer because i spent quite a bit time :)

Comment: you can add with exampe to your answer also, I think then I can give 1 vote up again (or not?)

Comment: @renathy i was trying to put up example. You can see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qW822/37/     But then somehow company list was not getting refreshed when i changed country and was taking lot of time, so just left it. But i made honest efforts